# Media Queries are not working

Tags: css, media-queries

Can anybody help me. My media queries are not working. I'm trying to change the padding on the navigation of my website. However, whenever I use the media query to change the padding on a 768px screen, nothing happens. I've added the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

But nothing happens. My media query looks like

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .menu-onesg-menu-container ul li a {
        padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why this isn't working???

Comment: Can you post more code? Possibly a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You can't expect a valid or accurate answer to your question in its current form because you've not provided enough detail; EG. you're using Wordpress (which you didn't declare) - what version? Are you using .less? Are your styles being overridden by others? As already pointed out, without all your styles, it's not possible to fix or give you any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the cause of the problem **Replace ; with ,**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Nope still doesn't like it

Comment: I'm using wordpress will that matter

Comment: @user2482793 I think it won't affect

Comment: Will the media queries work in a .less file or does it have to be .css

Comment: @user2482793 latest one will support media queries